# Unity how to control direction using AddForce instead of velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a ball gameObject which is launched via the code below using AddForce when the space Key is pressed, the value of ballForce is 400;

```
rigidBody.AddForce (new Vector2 (ballForce, ballForce));
```

Now to make the ball go left when it collides with the paddle I am using the code below:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
          if (col.gameObject.tag == "ball") {

          col.rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (-10f, col.gameObject.transform.position.y);
 }
}
```

This does the job but I wanted to know if there is another way to make the ball go left using AddForce (using the existing AddForce speed) instead of velocity as the ball seems to gain extra speed on collision.

Comment: Is there any need to add the force via code at all? Shouldn't the physics simulation handle the collision between the ball and the paddle?

Comment: Yes because I need to change the direction of the ball depending on which part of the paddle it collides with. There are actually 3 box colliders on the paddle which is to control the direction of the ball. The above example only mentioned going left but the paddle also has box colliders to make the ball go up and right.

Comment: I don't understand this. I think you don't understand how forces work in Unity. What AddForce does is it gives the body a momentum, like a punch. It's not a continuous force. It's applied only on the frame you call AddForce and after that the body gradually decelerates from drag or friction. So if you want to use another AddForce after collision just do so. `col.rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(your, force));`

Comment: but yet another cool approach you may be interested in is with Physics Materials. In your Assets folder right click > Create > Physics Material. Set the Bounciness of the material to 1 and Bounce Combine to Max. now drop this material in your collider's Material slot and the object will become 'bouncy' (is there such a word in English?). You won't need AddForce this way, but this might not be what you want

Comment: Nika, I tried col.rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(your, force)) - but how do I get that to move the ball left but still maintaining the same speed. If I use the same value of ball force as the initial launch then the ball behaves erratically.